# How to iterate through each row instance to delete data using between clause

Tags: php, mysql

**LINK TO SQL DATA**
https://www.mediafire.com/file/v46o3z5nmd0t7zl/pe_logevent.sql/file

**For each row that includes 'name1',**
I want to delete data
BETWEEN( 'name1' and ('name1' + 2min)) WHERE type = 'name2', 'name3', or 'name4'.

How do I iterate through each instance For each row that includes 'name1' ?

Below code works ... but only for the limit 1 row ...
How do you iterate this for more than 1 row?

I tried taking out "ORDER BY a.1 DESC LIMIT 1" but then I get

"Error updating record: Subquery returns more than 1 row".

Minimal Example:

```
$sql = "
    DELETE FROM a
    WHERE 
        a.1 BETWEEN 
        (SELECT a.1 FROM a WHERE a.2 = 'name1' ORDER BY a.1 DESC LIMIT 1  ) 
        AND 
        (SELECT a.1 + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE FROM a WHERE a.2 = 'name1' ORDER BY a.1 DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
        AND a.2 IN ('name2', 'name3', 'name4')";
```

Actual Code I'm trying to change:

```
$sql = "
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent
WHERE 
    pe_LogEvent_datetime BETWEEN 
    (SELECT pe_LogEvent_datetime FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot' ORDER BY pe_LogEvent_datetime DESC LIMIT 1  ) 
    AND 
    (SELECT pe_LogEvent_datetime + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = 'change_slot' ORDER BY pe_LogEvent_datetime DESC LIMIT 1 ) 
    AND pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash', 'pilot_death', 'eject')";
```

I think a way might be to do something like when you delete duplicate rows like example below?

```
$sql = '
DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent
WHERE 
    pe_LogEvent_type  IN (
    SELECT 
        pe_LastPilotDeath_pilotname 
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            pe_LastPilotDeath_pilotname,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY pe_LastPilotDeath_datetime
                ORDER BY pe_LastPilotDeath_datetime) AS row_num
        FROM 
            pe_LastPilotDeath
        
    ) t
    WHERE row_num > 1
)';
```

[Visual SQL DB Image with annotation of what I am trying to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYtVf.png)

Additional code example:

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT 
b.`pe_DataPlayers_lastname`, 
b.`pe_DataPlayers_updated`,
b.`pe_DataPlayers_id`


FROM `pe_DataPlayers` AS b 

GROUP BY b.`pe_DataPlayers_lastname`
ORDER BY b.`pe_DataPlayers_updated` DESC


")) {


//TABLE STARTS BELOW

    echo "<table class='table_stats' >";
    echo "<tr class='table_header'><th>Pilot</th><th>Last Flight Log</th></tr>"; // First Code                      
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['pe_DataPlayers_lastname'] . "</td>"; 
            echo "<td style='text-align: center'>" . $row['pe_DataPlayers_updated'] . "</td>";
            
            
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    
    $result->close();
}
```

Comment: Please consider providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query).

Comment: Ok I think I made a  minimal example, but I'm not sure what you mean by 'reproducible'

Comment: I added: For each row that includes 'change_slot', maybe that explains it a lot better ... look anything difficult it seems people just -1 or don't try ... I wouldn't be asking questions if it was easy. I wish I was better at explaining myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Drop table if exists
$sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pe_change_slots_dates';

// create a table for change slot dates start and end time
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pe_change_slots_dates (
pe_change_slots_dates_id INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
pe_change_slots_dates_starttime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
pe_change_slots_dates_endtime DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
';

//insert pe_change_slots_dates
   $sql = 'INSERT INTO pe_change_slots_dates 
    (pe_change_slots_dates_starttime,
    pe_change_slots_dates_endtime) 
        SELECT 
            pe_LogEvent_datetime AS pe_change_slots_dates_starttime,
            pe_LogEvent_datetime + INTERVAL 2 MINUTE AS pe_change_slots_dates_endtime
        FROM pe_LogEvent 
        WHERE pe_LogEvent_type = "change_slot"';
    

//delete extra IDs    
$sql = 'DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id IN (SELECT 
        pe.pe_LogEvent_id AS id
    FROM pe_LogEvent AS pe
        INNER JOIN pe_change_slots_dates AS csd ON (pe.pe_LogEvent_datetime BETWEEN 
csd.pe_change_slots_dates_starttime AND csd.pe_change_slots_dates_endtime)
    WHERE pe.pe_LogEvent_type IN ("crash", "pilot_death", "eject"))';
```

Comment: What is this insert statement doing?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this - 4rd solution:

```php
$timestamp = date('Y-M-d H:m:s');
// Insert new "change_slot" entry with time from $timestemp here

$sql="DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id IN (
            Select pe_LogEvent_id
            from pe_LogEvent
            where pe_LogEvent_datetime
            between "+$timestamp+" AND (SELECT DATE_SUB("+$timestamp+", INTERVAL 2 MINUTE))
            AND pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash','pilot_death','eject')
        )";
```

Mabye you have to change "DATE_SUB" with "DATE_ADD".
Be aware that queries which are combined variables and strings are **not secure** an you should **use a prepared statement instead**.

Also you could do this with trigger functions - in such a case you could only make the insert query and the database would run an function which handle the rest. If my solution works for your use case I can try to provide you such a function.

*How do I use a prepared statement with that?*

```php
// Source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM pe_LogEvent WHERE pe_LogEvent_id IN (
            Select pe_LogEvent_id
            from pe_LogEvent
            where pe_LogEvent_datetime
            between ? AND (SELECT DATE_SUB(?, INTERVAL 2 MINUTE))
            AND pe_LogEvent_type IN ('crash','pilot_death','eject')
        )");

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $timestamp, $timestamp);

// set parameters and execute
$timestamp = date('Y-M-d H:m:s');
$stmt->execute();

$timestamp = date('Y-M-d H:m:s');
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

A prepared statment can also be executed multiple time by just change the value of the paramters and call the execute function again.

```php
// set parameters and execute - first run
$timestamp = date('Y-M-d H:m:s');
$stmt->execute();

// set parameters and execute - second run
$timestamp = date('Y-M-d H:m:s');
$stmt->execute();
```

*Also when should I use a prepared statement?
When does it not matter and the code I already have is fine without much risk?*
To use prepared statemets is best practise. You should use it for every query but at least for queries which contain values typped in by the user (take a look at [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232399/discussion-on-answer-by-it-person-how-to-iterate-through-each-row-instance-to-de).